# Font Awesome Icons missing from asp:Gridview Export to Excel

Tags: asp.net, gridview, export-to-excel, font-awesome

I have a Gridview which has some FontAwesome checkmarks (fa-check) the problem is when I export the Grid to Excel these fields come out as blank. More so, at runtime the cell.Text value is the Empty string ("") so I cannot effectively replace the text with a "YES" for instance. 
I'm using the usual code for exporting (Stringwriter, HtmlTextWriter and then looping for each 
Gridview Row and TableCell therein)

Any clues on how to replace this at export time?

PS: I could have duplicate/hidden columns with YES NO instead of the Font Awesome icons, then hide and unhide them at export time, but I'm looking for a more graceful way.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Font Awesome will be using a character in the Unicode private-use-area for fa-check so the Excel exporter will be throwing it away. I don't know the export mechanism: is it provided by GridView?

Comment: No, the export mechanism is custom code.
Loop1  Rows
  Loop2 Cells
   Loop3 Controls (to remove controls and replace by literals)
then Response.Write, Output.Write, .Flush and .End

Comment: OK: I'd expect you to get [Unicode character 0xf00c](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/check/) for the check mark. If the string is definitely empty and not e.g. not properly rendered by VS, then I imagine ASP.NET is stripping it out before giving it to you: I know it's very careful about posted private-use-area characters. You may be able to dig into the ASP.NET source to work out what it's doing and if there's a way to bypass the filter, but I'd suggest going down the passing-the-data-a-different-way route: I'd hope there's a more elegant way than hidden columns though!

Comment: Can you edit the question and show us part of Designer code to check how you used FA?

Answer (score 0):

Please check out:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/

It is a more graceful way to export to XLS and has many ways to customize your export.

In addition .. since FA Fonts are font based ... including a link to your resource file so excel can find the font your trying to render?

Comment: It is always a good idea to post the code/steps needed to solve the problem and the link instead of just a link. That way, no navigation away from SO is needed to solve the problem :)

Comment: Link only answers are [grounds for removal](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251006/2596334). The [reasons for this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/235574) are legion. Please read ["How do I write a good answer?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)